# Strange Disk Image File (.dmg) problem - deleted files in xyz.dmg do not relinquish file space

Tags: disk-utility, dmg

Hardware & OS used:

- Mac Studio M1 Max 32GB mem 1TB SSD Mac OS Ventura 13.2
- Mac Mini M1 16GB mem, 1TB SSD Mac OS Ventura 13.2
- Mac Mini Intel i7 32GB mem, 1TB SSD, Mac OS Ventura 13.2

**Background**:
Currently using Veracrypt software container to store sensitive files. Update files within this secured container (after mounting) with Free File Sync works perfectly.

**Objective**:
Would like to change this way of operating to Apple’s own software ecosystem by using an encrypted .DMG, created with disk utility.

**Followed procedure**:
In Disk Utility, select **File** > **New Image** > **Blank Image**, then save with name `File.dmg` and select location.
Select name, select **Size**: 1GB, **Format**: APFS, select **Encryption** (enter password), **Partitions**: GUID Partition map, **Image Format**: read/write disk image, then click **Save**

File.dmg was created with a password. Works perfectly, mount and dismount.

**The problem/issue on all three Macs**:

If I now manually add files to this mounted disk image, all works fine. However, when I want to delete some files, the obsolete files disappear in the Finder view (also when displaying hidden files) but they keep occupying space in `file.dmg`.
You can perfectly see this with the “Get Info” tab in Finder.

So my allocated 1GB gets very rapidly full as deleted files don’t hand back available file space to the system. I have tried all sorts of combinations (parameters) while creating a .dmg in Disk Utility, but the problem remains.

The only way in which I am able to reclaim the “lost” file space is to manually empty the Trash.  I think this is not right as deleting files on an HDD or SSD should relinquish the space the moment the files are deleted and are being placed in the Trash, this pending final deletion.

Is anyone else experiencing this problem or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Deleted data goes to the Trash. Files in Trash are still considered as part of the total disk usage until the Trash is emptied.

Trash does not recycle itself like Windows, though it has a 30-day timer [optional] to selectively fully delete files older than 30 days, similar to how many things on iOS work. If you start with an empty Trash bin, then you can see this in operation more easily. you can see items appear & disappear as you mount/unmount the dmg.

If you want to permanently delete items without emptying the entire Trash, delete them using
 <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>  <kbd>Delete ⌦</kbd>
You can also selectively delete items from Trash permanently by the same method, or from the right click menu.

Comment: @Tesujin, thanks you for your reply, really appreciated. So If I understand you correctly you cannot use a .dmg as a dynamically repository to add and delete without a human intervention i.e. delete trash manually in order to free up space? I dont know if you are familiar with Veracrypt on Mac - secured container where you and delete without this problem That is also a "virtual" drive like .dmg. I am a bit puzzled. Is there no way to circumvent this prob without the manual trash intervention? thanks.

Comment: @fganon Delete files immediately, without sending them to Trash.  That's the only way.

Comment: As Marc says. I don't know why VeraCrypt would do it that way, it's more a Windows standard than Mac. macOS only does this normally on a foreign file system, one that can't handle .Trashes properly.

Comment: @Tetsujin & Marc. I added a comment last night but something when wrong as it is not visible on the thread - anyway, herewith.  I did some tests and I think I see what you mean. Is the following statement than correct? When deleting files in Mac OS, on no mater what storage (internal& external), all those deleted files are displayed in the bin (trash), but the file space from where they originated from will only be freed up when you empty the trash.

Comment: Correct. The Trash is still a catalogued area of the disk & still 'uses space', unlike Windows, which will automatically thin space in Trash as required. This makes Mac's recovery from Trash a certainly & Windows a matter of 'good luck'.

Comment: @Marc & Tetsujin - additional question - is it also correct than that files deleted and shown in the trash (bin) are in reality still resident on their originated storage but invisible, and the bin only has "pointers" as where they were. I don't know how to phrase my question properly but otherwise said, if I delete a file of 10Gb on an external disk, this file is not copied to the bin which resides on my internal mac SSD. So I would not incur additional writes (wear & tear) on this SSD ?

Comment: On a regular disk, yes, it's merely the pointer that is moved. idk how this translates to potential wear on a mounted disk image's underlying file system. [It's not something I've ever worried about, SSDs are not as fragile as people seem to think. I've two here approaching their 10th birthday, in daily use as system disks;)

Comment: @Tetsijun, okay clear - think I learned something here - also I figured out ( following your comment above) why Veracrypt does not have these issues. In order to work with Veracrypt one has to install MacFuse which is a file system driver/utility in order to handle Veracrypt's "Alien" file system. Apparently a file delete in that environment is instantly. So you were absolutely right with your Windows recycle example.  Thanks again to both you and Marc for taking the time to help me.

Comment: @fganon All volumes have their own Trash.  If you move a file to trash on an external volume, then the files go to that volume's trash.